# Using perl, how do I search a text file for _NN (at the end of a word) and print the word in front?

Tags: perl

This gives the whole line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$file = 'output.txt';
open(txt, $file);
while($line = <txt>) {
  print "$line" if $line =~ /_NN/;
}
close(txt);
```

Comment: You need to be more specific to get a working regex. What characters will the "word" consist of? Is `"w-12#"` or `"q:w"` a valid word? Will there be other irrelevant characters nearby, such as `"123_BB,word_NN"`? In short, be as specific about the word you want, and the context it is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer script reads a bit awkwardly, and has a couple of potential errors.  I'd rewrite the main logic loop like so:

```
foreach my $line (grep { /expend_VB/ } @sentences) {
   my @nouns = grep { /_NN/ } split /\s+/, $line; 
   foreach my $word (@nouns) {
      $word =~ s/_NN//;
      print "$word\n";
   }
   print "$line\n" if scalar(@nouns);
}
```

You need to put the **my** declaration inside the loop - otherwise it will persist longer than you want it to, and could conceivably cause problems later.

**foreach** is a more common perl idiom for iterating over a list.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => "all";
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8") || die;

my $file = "output.txt";
open(TEXT, "< :utf8", $file)  || die "Can't open $file: $!";
while(<TEXT>) {
    print "$1\n" while /(\w+)_NN\b/g;
}
close(TEXT)                  || die "Can't close $file: $!";
```

Comment: THANKS! I may need help later, since this is just the beginning, but you've gotten me off to a great start!

Answer (score 1):

```
print "$1" if $line =~ /(\S+)_NN/;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => "all";
my $search_key = "expend";       ## CHANGE "..." to <>

open(my $tag_corpus, '<', "ch13tagged.txt") or die $!;

my @sentences = <$tag_corpus>; # This breaks up each line into list
my @words;

for (my $i=0; $i <= @sentences; $i++) {
    if ( defined( $sentences[$i] ) and $sentences[$i] =~ /($search_key)_VB.*/i) {
        @words = split /\s/,$sentences[$i]; ## \s is a whitespace

        for (my $j=0; $j <= @words; $j++) {  
#FILTER if word is noun:            
            if ( defined( $words[$j] ) and $words[$j] =~ /_NN/) {


#PRINT word and sentence:
                print "**",split(/_\S+/,$words[$j]),"**", "\n";
                print split(/_\S+/,$sentences[$i]), "\n"

            }
        } ## put print sentences here to print each sentence after all the nouns inside
    }
}

close $tag_corpus     || die "Can't close $tag_corpus: $!";
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm not quite sure what this answer here shows, it's very terse. If it's your existing solution/starting point it would be more appropriate as an edit to the original question rather than an answer on its own though. If it's an answer it would be worth elaborating so that other people who find it later via google can see how it answered your question more clearly.